# python generating xml

Tags: python, linux, zabbix

i am generating an XML template for zabbix using python minidom

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.dom import minidom
#from xml.etree.cElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment
import sys

def prettify(elem):
    """returns a xml in pretty format"""
    orig_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(orig_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="    ")

def createXml():
    zabbix_export = Element('zabbix_export',{'version':'1.0','date':'07/03/2012','time':'18:40'})
    #zabbix_export = Element('zabbix_export')
    comment = Comment('Generated in python')
    zabbix_export.append(comment)

    hosts = SubElement(zabbix_export,'hosts')

    host = SubElement(hosts, 'host', {'name':'Template_KSHK_Stats'})
    host.text = 'this child contains text'

    proxy_hostid = SubElement(host, 'proxy_hostid')
    proxy_hostid.text = 'this is the subchild'

    useip = SubElement(host, 'useip')
    useip.text = '0'

    ip = SubElement(host, 'ip')
    ip.text = '0.0.0.0'

    port = SubElement(host, 'port')
    port.text = '0'

    print prettify(zabbix_export)

def main():
    createXml()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the output i get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<zabbix_export date="07/03/2012" time="18:40" version="1.0">
    <!-- Generated in python -->
    <hosts>
        <host name="Template_KSHK_Stats">
            this child contains text
            <proxy_hostid>
                this is the subchild
            </proxy_hostid>
            <useip>
                0
            </useip>
            <ip>
                0.0.0.0
            </ip>
            <port>
                0
            </port>
            <status>
                3
            </status>
```

i would like the subelements in the host tree to be in this format,

```
proxy_hostid>this is the subchild</proxy_hostid>
<useip>0</useip>
<ip>0.0.0.0</ip>
<port>0</port>
<status>3</status>
```

but because of the prettifyhack from http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/xml/etree/ElementTree/create.html

zabbix does not read the subelements properly..

any idea how i can fix this??

**FIXED:**

using

```
def prettify(elem):
    """returns a xml in pretty format"""
    orig_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(orig_string)
    uglyXml = reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ")
    text_re = re.compile('>\n\s+([^<>\s].*?)\n\s+</', re.DOTALL)
    prettyXml = text_re.sub('>\g<1></', uglyXml)
    return prettyXml
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't prettify it. As mentioned on Dougs page, it is t make it easier on human eyes (and so helpful if you need to debug the XML) but this will change the contents in some cases. Yours is one of these cases.